# String interpolation and placeholder variable

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

Why in the REPL this expression fails:

```
List("a", "b").foreach { System.out.println(s"Valor=$_") }
```

with this error:

```
<console>:1: error: unclosed string literal
```

whereas this other one succeeds:

```
List("a", "b").foreach { x => System.out.println(s"Valor=$x") }
```

I suspect that the "_" variable isn't supported.

Is this a bug or by design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message you're showing is different than what I get with Scala 2.11.1:

```
scala> List("a", "b").foreach { System.out.println(s"Valor=$_") }
<console>:1: error: error in interpolated string: identifier or block expected
       List("a", "b").foreach { System.out.println(s"Valor=$_") }
                                                            ^
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but '}' found.
       List("a", "b").foreach { System.out.println(s"Valor=$_") }
                                                                ^
```

To answer your question now. [SIP-11](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NdxNxZYodPA-c4MLr33KzwzKFkzm9iW9POexT9PkJsU/edit?hl=en_US#), which defined string interpolation for Scala, disallows identifiers starting with anything else than a letter. That may be a bit too restritive, but it makes sense for the special `_` identifier if you consider the desugaring of interpolated strings.

Your example:

```
List("a", "b").foreach { System.out.println(s"Valor=$_") }
```

Would have been desugared to this:

```
List("a", "b").foreach { System.out.println(StringContext("Valor=", "").s(_)) }
```

Which clearly shows that `_` can't be associated with the param of the function passed to `foreach`. Here's the error message reported when trying to execute the desugaring:

```
scala> List("a", "b").foreach { System.out.println(StringContext("Valor=", "").s(_)) }
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String => ?
              List("a", "b").foreach { System.out.println(StringContext("Valor=", "").s(_)) }
```

In short, this happens because of the way desugaring works.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. The error message I showed is for Scala 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading, but the main issue here is that you are passing an anonymous function to println:

List("a", "b").foreach { System.out.println(s"Valor=$_") }

is equivalent to

List("a", "b").foreach { System.out.println(x => s"Valor=$x") }

You already have one working version, another version which shows that _ is definitely supported:

List("a", "b").foreach (System.out println "Valor=" + _)

The above works cause order of evaluation makes it equivalent to:

List("a", "b").foreach (x => System.out println "Valor=" + x)